# Using regex to duplicate a selection and replacing some characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

Probably a terrible title.

I am trying to take the following:

```
Joe Dane
Bob Sagget
Whitney Houston
Some
Other
Test
```

And trying to produce:

```
JOE_DANE("Joe Dane"),
BOB_SAGGET("Bob Sagget"),
WHITNEY_HOUSTON("Whitney Houston"),
SOME("Some"),
OTHER("Other"),
TEST("Test"),
```

I'm using Notepad++ and am close but not good enough at regex to figure out the remaining expression. So far, this is what I have:

Find what: `(^.*)`
Replace with: `\1 \(\"\1\"\),`
Produces: `Joe Dane("Joe Dane"),`

I've tried replacing with: `\U$1 \(\"\1\"\),` but this also impacts the second instance of `\1` with upper case. It also does not replace the whitespace with an underscore `_`.

Comment: [tag:notepadd++] tag added

Comment: Could you have more than 2 words in a line? How many?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in a single step.

---

If you don't have more than 2 words in a line:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\S+)(?: (\S+))?$`
- Replace with: `\U$1(?2_$2)\E\("$0"\),`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
(\S+)           # group 1, 1 or more non space
(?: (\S+))?     # non capture group, a space, group 2, 1 or more non space, optional
$
```

**Replacement:**

```
\U          # uppercased
$1          # group 1
(?2_$2)     # if group 2 exists, add and underscore before
\E          # end uppercase
\("$0"\),   # the whole match with parens and quote
```

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

---

If you have more than 2 words (up to 5), use:

- Find `^(\S+)(?: (\S+))?(?: (\S+))?(?: (\S+))?(?: (\S+))?`
- Replace: `\U$1(?2_$2)(?3_$3)(?4_$4)(?5_$5)\E\("$0"\),`

I you have more thans five word, add as many `(?: (\S+))?` as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You might do it in 2 steps, first matching any char 1+ more times from the start of the string.

**Find what**

```
^.+
```

For the first replacement you can use `\E` to end the activation of `\U` and use the full match `$0`

**Replace with**

```
\U$0\E\("$0"\),
```

[image]

For the second step, to replace the spaces with underscores, you could skip over the text between parenthesis, and match spaces between uppercase chars.

**Find what**

```
\(".*?"\)(*SKIP)(*F)|[A-Z]+\K\h+(?=[A-Z])
```

- `\(".*?"\)` Match from `("` till `")`
- `(*SKIP)(*F)|` Skip this part of the match
- `[A-Z]+\K` Match uppercase chars and use `\K` to clear the current match buffer (forget what is matches do far)
- `\h+(?=[A-Z])` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars and assert an uppercase char to the right

**Replace with** `_`

[image]